# Add clickable links to dashboard of rails_admin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

Using rails_admin gem, I want to create a clickable link to rails_admin dashboard's left hand side bar.

Path of that link should be according to the rails path. I don't want to add any model for the same.

Please help me in adding the link.

Answer (score 1):

You can add in your rails admin initializer:

```
config.navigation_static_links = {
  'Dashboard' => '/admin' #or whatever you used to mount RailsAdmin in your routes file
}
```

Comment: This will add static link to dashboard not the right side bar